# Unable to call methods in model from controller in codeigniter 3.0.5

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am working with **CodeIgniter 3.0.5** and I have done a fair share of research to find the solution to my relatively simple to solve problem.

Just have a look at my case.

I have a model with file name `Technology_model.php`

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Technology_Model extends CI_Model
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }          

        public function getData()
        {
             $query = $this->db->get('technology');
             return $query->result();
        }
    }
?>
```

I've loaded this Model in my controller file `Technology.php`and I'm trying to access the methods in my model.

```
<?php   
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Technology extends CI_Controller 
{

    // *******Constructor*******
    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();            
    }
    // *******Constructor*******

    public function index() 
    {
         $this->load->model('Technology_Model');
         //Model loads fine..checked

         $data['records'] = 
            $this->Technology_model->getData(); //*** <=ERROR in this line
    }
}
?>
```

The solutions I found were all about changing the character casing of the following:

1. name of the Model class,
2. model filename,
3. name of the model when being called in the controller,
4. name of the model when calling the method after being loaded

I have tried all the Naming conventions. The model is getting loaded. But when I try to call the methods in the model, I get the following errors.

Some say its a Bug in CI 3.0.5. I have configured my database, loaded database library in autoload.php and tried all solutions provided, though they didn't work out.

Please help me find a solution.
Thanks.
    [These are the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN2NM.png)

### SOLVED

The models should be named, as in my case, **Technology_model.php** .
Also the respective class for this model would be **Technology_Model**

Comment: Hi friends..I tried to run this in a new CI project..and it works perfectly fine.
I think the problem is with the configurations that I have made in the `config.php` file or in other configuration files of my current project. @Dfriend @Narf @Tpojka @theruss. I'll notify you people in case I get the solution..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$this->load->model()` capitalization does not matter with regard to finding the model class - `Technology_Model` will work as will `technology_model`. However, the string used will be the name of the *instance* of the class and IS case sensitive - like any other PHP var.

In other words, if you do this:

```
$this->load->model('Technology_Model');
```

then to access methods of that class instance you need to use the same (case sensitive) word ie,

```
$this->Technology_Model->getData();
```

Not using the exact same string results in the error you have been seeing.

All that said, my practice is to use all lowercase for instance names. For file and class names only the first character is uppercase. So the file would be `Technology_model.php`, with a class definition of `class Technology_model extends CI_Model`.

It would be loaded in a controller with `$this->load->model('technology_model');`

Comment: I tried all the combination of Character Casing..With filenames and also with class names...Still not working..I'm certain its not a name issue..I've tried all combinations

About :   $this->load->controller('Site');

I'm calling methods from Site controller from inside the Technology controller..Not relevant to my problem..Hence I'm removing it from the code here.

Comment: @RahulShenoy, check out the info I added to the answer.

Comment: I tried what you asked me to..

    $this->load->model('technology_model');
    
    $data['records'] = $this->technology_model->getData();

Sadly, the error still persists...
Message: Undefined property: Technology::$technology_model

Comment: @Rahul, have you rename your file to Technology_model.php?

Comment: @MSI, The problem was with the configuration in the config.php file as I had suspected. Hence the name of the file wasn't the actual issue. I was trying to do something That I forgot later on. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DFriend 's answer, although I am using some kind of distinctive variable naming personal standardization in a way with no problems:

File name:

```
Technology_m.php // sparing few chars
```

Class name:

```
Technology_m
```

Loader method argument:

```
$this->load->model('Technology_m');
```

Approaching model method/property:

```
$this->Technology_m->getData();
```

Thing is in my internal systematisation and variable convention since you can call model with `ucfirst()` but not library itself. I use to have models with ucfirst() in all calls in my controller respecting model convention as I described above, but also I use to have library call from controller that follows `strtolower()` standard. That way, seeing the code snippet on first sight, I am able to determine if something is model or library (instance/property/method).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like CI basically cannot find your model's PHP file and therefore cannot call `getData()` on what it thinks is a non-existent class. You haven't given us CI's directory structure, but AFAIK depending on where your model is, then the path to its PHP file needs to reflect that.

For example, my own admin models are in: *Codeigniter/application/models/admin*. So if I need to call an admin model from a controller I do it like this:

`$this->load->model('admin/my_model', 'MyAdmin', true);
$data = $this->MyAdmin->get();`

Note that relative path to my model dir in the first param and also the 2nd and param which declares a variable on which you can run your model's method(s) (Optional, just using it as an example).